# Is INT_MIN/-1 defined behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, math, integer-overflow, integer-division

I have the following code for `INT_MIN/-1`. I would expect for this to have came out to be INT_MAX+1 (or 0 with rollover). However, the actual result I get is INT_MIN. This is my test code:

```
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int min=INT_MIN;
  int res=min/-1;
  printf("result: %i\n", res);
  printf("max: %i min: %i\n", INT_MAX, INT_MIN);
  return 0;
}
```

Is this implementation specific and/or undefined behavior?

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined, only unsigned overflow is defined as "modulo `1 << width`".

Comment: `INT_MAX + 1` isn't 0 with rollover, it's `INT_MIN`.

Comment: It's defined behaviour if the representation of signed integers is ones' complement or signed-magnitude, because then no overflow happens.

Comment: @DanielFischer That can't be true. If it was true, then one could use ones' complement to store an entire document in a single `int`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Just in case: in my comment I meant that `INT_MIN/-1` is defined behaviour in ones' complement or signed-magnitude representations (because then the mathematical result is representable as an `int` too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this implementation specific and/or undefined behavior?

Yes, **signed** integer overflow is undefined behavior. Per paragraph 5/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [...]

Notice, that the same does not apply to *unsigned* arithmetic. As specified in paragraph 3.9.1/4 and footnote 46:

> Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo `2^n` where `n` is the number
>   of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer. [...]
>
> This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
>   unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the
>   resulting unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 3):

This is signed integer overflow and thus undefined behavior, this `Cert` document on how to  [Ensure that operations on signed integers do not result in overflow](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow?showComments=false) is great and as far as I can tell covers all the instances. This is the `if` statement from the `Division` section that covers your question:

```
if ( (sl2 == 0) || ( (sl1 == LONG_MIN) && (sl2 == -1) ) ) {
  /* Handle error condition */
}
else {
  result = sl1 / sl2;
}
```